# Cookies not saving to Chrome/Edge, localhost or server

Tags: json, google-chrome, cookies, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to have cookies set, and then subsequently loaded upon the next page. I currently add items to my "Cart" and upon checking logs and inspecting, they are not being logged to console, but then not actually being set. This is in javascript, server on node.

```
const shoppingCart = [];

//Convery array to JSON string and set as cookie
function saveCartToCookie() {
  const cartJSON = JSON.stringify(shoppingCart);
  console.log("Saving cart to cookie:", cartJSON);
  document.cookie = `shoppingCart=${cartJSON}; path=/`;
}

function loadCartFromCookie() {
  const cookieData = document.cookie.split(';').find(cookie => cookie.trim().startsWith('shoppingCart='));
  if (cookieData) {
    const cartJSON = cookieData.split('=')[1];
    console.log("Loading cart from cookie:", cartJSON);
    shoppingCart.length = 0; // Clear the current cart
    shoppingCart.push(...JSON.parse(cartJSON)); // Load cart from cookie
  }
}
```

Pulled into my html as such;

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="../utils/cart.js"></script>
```

I have tried chrome, edge, as well as having it hosted on localhost and my github. Any idea where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> document.cookie = `shoppingCart=${cartJSON}; path=/`;

In your code, I found a problem with symbols. You should be using single quotes instead of backquote. It should be something like this:

```
document.cookie = 'shoppingCart=${cartJSON}; path=/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was trying to save the cookie when working on my project through file protocol (`file://`) instead of using localhost (`localhost:3000/whatever`). File protocol doesn't work with cookies!